# Python Opencv morphological closing gives src data type = 0 is not supported

Tags: python, opencv, mathematical-morphology

I'm trying to morphologically close a volume with a ball structuring element created by the function `SE3 = skimage.morphology.ball(8)`.
When using `closing = cv2.morphologyEx(volume_start, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, SE)` it returns TypeError: src data type = 0 is not supported
Do you know how to solve this issue? 
Thank you

Comment: Distantly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30989915/typeerror-src-data-type-15-is-not-supported http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25137163/opencvsrc-is-not-a-numerical-tuple

Answer (score 14):

Make sure `volume_start` is `dtype=uint8`. You can convert it with `volume_start = np.array(volume_start, dtype=np.uint8)`.

Or nicer:
`volume_start = volume_start.astype(np.uint8)`

Answer (score 0):

The same error occurred to me while calling the `erode` function on a binarized image that I binarized (from a grayscale image of 0 to 255 values) like this:

```
bin_img = grayscale_img > 125
```

I guess the `>` operator "swallowed" the type, or changed it to the openCV's type of code `0`.

I **solved** it by doing the binarization like this:

```
ret, bin_img = cv2.threshold(grayscale, 125, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
```

`ret` is the threshold value (125 in this case), and `bin_img` is the resulting binary image.